# Firebird SqlConnection

Tags: sql, firebird2.1

I have problem with connecting to firebird tables. I tried every connection string i could find on internet but it doesn't work. Problem comes when i open connection

Here is code

```
    private void RutinskiPopis_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;Database=localhost:D:\\TDWORK.FDB;Data Source=localhost;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Opis, Broj FROM PLNAZIVI", con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comboBox1_Data((IDataRecord)dr);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Can anyone help me with that connection string?
Here is full connection string

> initial catalog=D:\TDWORK.FDB;data source=localhost;user id=SYSDBA;role=admin

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/

Comment: I already tried all that and not working. Tried it again and still same. First of all i have not supported keywords (role, port, Dialect, charset, minpoolsize, maxpoolsize, server type). I tried not using that but then again just freeze when opening connection

Comment: Ok, nobody told me i need to use FbConnection and no SqlConnection :)
Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `SqlConnection`, which can only connect to Microsoft SQL Server. For Firebird you need to use `FbConnection`.

See for examples: [.NET - examples of use](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using FbConnection instead of SqlConnection, and then using standard firebird connection string.